# package javax.persistence does not exist despite Netbeans adding the Eclipselink module

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, persistence, eclipselink

Two part question:

first part:  which JAR is required?  Does not javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar have the required classes, in particular javax.persistence.*?

[image]

stack trace as so:

```
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/build
Updating property file: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/build/classes
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/build/classes/META-INF
Copying 1 file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/build/classes/META-INF
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/build/empty
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 2 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/build/classes
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:8: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.*;
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
  symbol: class Entity
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
@Table(name = "fud30_groups", catalog = "fudforum", schema = "")
  symbol: class Table
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
@NamedQueries({
  symbol: class NamedQueries
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    @Id
  symbol:   class Id
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  symbol:   class GeneratedValue
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    @Basic(optional = false)
  symbol:   class Basic
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    @Column(name = "id")
  symbol:   class Column
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    @Basic(optional = false)
  symbol:   class Basic
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    @Column(name = "name")
  symbol:   class Column
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
    @Basic(optional = false)
  symbol:   class Basic
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    @Column(name = "inherit_id")
  symbol:   class Column
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    @Basic(optional = false)
  symbol:   class Basic
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
    @Column(name = "forum_id")
  symbol:   class Column
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    @Basic(optional = false)
  symbol:   class Basic
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    @Column(name = "groups_opt")
  symbol:   class Column
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    @Basic(optional = false)
  symbol:   class Basic
  location: class Fud30Groups
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/src/javaapplication12/Fud30Groups.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    @Column(name = "groups_opti")
  symbol:   class Column
  location: class Fud30Groups
18 errors
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/nbproject/build-impl.xml:605: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication12/nbproject/build-impl.xml:246: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Second part of the question is, what's (potentially) wrong with Netbeans?  Until yesterday, it seemed that the IDE would automagically add required classes to the classpath when, as here, generating an @Entity class from an existing database.  In this particular case, Netbeans did add JAR's.

However, because they're added externally to the project there's no lib folder.  Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough yet to really dive into build.xml to see what's going on, but from the Library Manager it looks like they are as so:

```
thufir@dur:~$ tree netbeans-7.1.1/java/modules/ext/eclipselink/
netbeans-7.1.1/java/modules/ext/eclipselink/
├── eclipselink-2.3.0.jar
├── eclipselink-jpa-modelgen-2.3.0.jar
├── javax.persistence-2.0.jar
└── org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_1.0.0.jar

0 directories, 4 files
thufir@dur:~$
```

It just seems to not fit with my recollection that additional steps, downloading whichever JAR's are missing, was required in the past.  Could a setting in Netbeans be wrong or corrupted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lucky number 13, Netbeans project 13, as identical as possible to Netbeans project 12, builds fine (well, not fine, but it does build):

clean and build:

```
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build
Updating property file: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build/classes
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build/classes/META-INF
Copying 1 file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build/classes/META-INF
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build/empty
Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 2 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build/classes
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
Note: Creating non-static metadata factory ...
Note: Found Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory, with value: false
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Found Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory, with value: false
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory]'
1 warning
Copying 2 files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication13/build/classes
compile:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

The two projects:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ tree JavaApplication12
JavaApplication12
├── build
│   ├── built-jar.properties
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── META-INF
│   │       └── persistence.xml
│   ├── empty
│   └── generated-sources
│       └── ap-source-output
├── build.xml
├── manifest.mf
├── nbproject
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   └── private.properties
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
└── src
    ├── javaapplication12
    │   ├── Fud30Groups.java
    │   └── JavaApplication12.java
    └── META-INF
        └── persistence.xml

11 directories, 12 files
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ tree JavaApplication13
JavaApplication13
├── build
│   ├── built-jar.properties
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── javaapplication13
│   │   │   ├── Fud30Groups_.class
│   │   │   ├── Fud30Groups.class
│   │   │   ├── Fud30Groups.java
│   │   │   ├── JavaApplication13.class
│   │   │   └── JavaApplication13.java
│   │   └── META-INF
│   │       └── persistence.xml
│   ├── empty
│   └── generated-sources
│       └── ap-source-output
│           └── javaapplication13
│               └── Fud30Groups_.java
├── build.xml
├── lib
│   ├── CopyLibs
│   │   └── org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
│   ├── eclipselink
│   │   ├── eclipselink-2.3.0.jar
│   │   ├── javax.persistence-2.0.jar
│   │   └── org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_1.0.0.jar
│   ├── eclipselinkmodelgen
│   │   └── eclipselink-jpa-modelgen-2.3.0.jar
│   └── nblibraries.properties
├── manifest.mf
├── nbproject
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   ├── config.properties
│   │   └── private.properties
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
└── src
    ├── javaapplication13
    │   ├── Fud30Groups.java
    │   └── JavaApplication13.java
    └── META-INF
        └── persistence.xml

17 directories, 25 files
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$
```

The difference apparently being that project 13 has a ./lib folder, while project 12 is using "external" JAR's.

Perhaps my Netbeans install is corrupt, or a setting wrong, or I've got the wrong approach to project 12?  I'd like to do it with external JAR's, as project 12 does, because various features, like the Library Manager, work better.